# JAVA jTable - How to make all cells non-editable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-6.9

I have a jTable calendar that works just fine and I just want the user not be able to edit anything. How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!!

PS: I use netbeans 6.9.

Answer (score 9):

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        //all cells false
        return false;
    }
};

table.setModel(tableModel);
```

Comment: @Matthew - when I try to implement this, it makes my table disappear. Does it matter that my table is in a JScrollPane? Like this:

`JScrollPane editPatDocScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
      JTable editPatDocTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
      
      editPatDocScrollPane.setViewportView(editPatDocTable);`

Comment: @Jona I don't see why that should make any difference. The cells are still there, they're just read-only. If you need help with your situation I suggest you  open a new question with a self-contained example that demonstrates the disappearing table.

Comment: I had the same problem. What I did was JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames); and then setModel. But that overrides your data and columnNames ! so you have to initialize your defaultTableModel with your data and columnNames and then pass it to your JTable.

Answer (score 3):

Simply return `false` in the isCellEditable() implementation of your TableModel

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Will that keep people from clicking on the values and changing them. That probably keeps people from saving data back to a file if they check with a conditional statement.

Comment: Let me ask this. If you implement a JTable model you are basically creating the methods that will search through the two-dimensional array. So if you set isCellEditable = false then you just would not write any data back to the array. And when you click on say a save button then it will write the new info in the JTable to the object array or if you have a keylistener on any of the keys. If key changes write new values. What if you do not want them to be able to click in the boxes and even change the values at this point.

Answer (score 3):

in your table model (which extends AbstractTableModel), you need to implement as such:

```
     public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
           //table is not editable
            public boolean isCellEditable() {
                return false;
            }
     }
```

Comment: This is a good solution. But note: the TableModel might actually extend DefaultTableModel in Cristian's code.  There not typically a good reason to extend AbstractTableModel when you can just extend DefaultTableModel.

Comment: well, normally i don't use DefaultTableModel as you cannot specify your own datatype and more importantly, it uses vectors of vectors to store things which can get annoying. but yeah, for plain old convenience, DefaultTableModel is the easier choice for such a small task since it provides most of the implementations! personally, i avoid it though.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, maybe this is a new feature, but I found that I could use:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
...
table.setEnabled(false);
```

And that did the job for me.

Comment: model.cellEditable != view.enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try this code; it's simple and easy to understand.

```
 DefaultTableModel  model =new DefaultTableModel(6,8);
 table = new JTable(model){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 2485117672771964339L;

            @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable ( int row, int column )
                {
                    return editable;
                }
      };
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `JTable` instead `JTAble`?